# Creating setup files for C#

Tags: c#, installation, setup-project

I am creating a setup file for a C# application, and I am successful in that. I set the default location property, `[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]`, to

```
[ProgramFilesFolder]\[ProductName]
```

While installing it it installs into `C:\Programfiles\Myapplication`. My problem is that I do not want to install in the Programfiles folder. I want it to install in
`C:\myapplication`.

I can change this at the time of installation, but my client requirement is that he can directly install without any changes by him.

How do I set this path in the setup application itself?

Comment: Did you even try removing the **[ProgramFilesFolder]**? What else did you try?

Comment: @user703526-Do you see ? people start talking about your problem.

Comment: Why do you want to install it directly under C:? I hate programs that do that

Comment: @Oskar he wrote _"my client requirement..."_

Comment: @Reniuz Yeah, I saw that. But still, why?

Comment: @Oskar because client is always right :)

Comment: @Reniuz That's what they say, but I've never seen it happen :(

Answer (score 3):

Replace `[ProgramFilesFolder]` with `C:`:

```
C:\[ProductName]
```